# Is Mdb-card still available or not? and if not what is the alternative?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I found a code for a contact us page using Angular material, here is the page:
https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/forms/contact/

so when i try it i get this error :
'mdb-card' is not a known element:
1. If 'mdb-card' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.

Comment: You'll need to import the [module](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/getting-started/modules/) that component is provided by, whatever that may be. See the [quick start](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/getting-started/quick-start/).

Comment: Hi, @houssem-bouallagui! Welcome to SO! Please, add the code you're trying to use to your question via editing it. The linked tutorial is big and people who will be trying to help you will be confused. Its better to keep the link as an additional info source, while giving all required question details right in the body of your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install MDBBootstrapModule and import it in your app.module.ts:

```
import { MDBBootstrapModule } from 'angular-bootstrap-md';
 imports: [
MDBBootstrapModule.forRoot(),
 ]
```

[Follow MDBootstrap Installation in this link](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/getting-started/quick-start/)

Comment: Fixed it. Appreciate it Pal.